# I want to remove deprecated S3 buckets (buckets with deletion policy) from Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to remove deprecated S3 buckets (buckets with deletion policy) from Cloudformation. by using cloud formation

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: if there is deprecated buckets (If these buckets remain in Cloudformation after they are deleted) in cloud formation, how can i delete those buckets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete an S3 bucket that was not deleted by stack using CF template. You will have to delete it manually.